# Does akka FSM should be used in batch operations?

Tags: scala, akka, batch-processing, fsm

I have read about [FSM in akka](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/fsm.html). Should be they used for batch opertions? E.g. should I store for example 100 messages and pass them into batch method? Or akka FSM just designed to work with states and should not be used for performance optimiztion with "classical" batch operations?

Answer (score 0):

You certainly could use it like that if you want to, I see no direct problem with it. It all depends on your exact use case though.

In general switching a state is as expensive as an `Actor#become`, which may be little or much – depending on your access patterns.